# Rust: Write stdout into a buffer or String

Tags: rust, process, io, stdout

I'm trying to spawn a process and log its stdout to a file.

My attempt was:

```
let mut log = String::new();

let output = Command::new("git")
        .current_dir(&cwd)
        .arg("pull")
        .arg("--rebase=merges")
        .output()
        .expect("Error doing git pull");

log.push_str("\nOUTPUT\n");
log.push_str(&output.stdout);
```

But this gives an error of mismatched types. How can I capture output.stdout to write into a String, or better, to a file?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried matching the types? Command::output returns a vector of bytes, while push_str takes a `&str`. If only there was some function like that took a sequence of bytes and turned it into a `&str`. If it existed it probably would be defined in `std::str` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Command` output is represented as a series of bytes. Use [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) to convert it to a `str`:

```rust
use std::str;
log.push_str(match str::from_utf8(&output.stdout) {
    Ok(val) => val,
    Err(_) => panic!("got non UTF-8 data from git"),
});
```

[Try it in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5ec59d316ef16e96718af1ecb1ebe9a3)

Comment: Also, if the command may output non-UTF8 chars, and you prefer to convert the non-utf8 characters into a replacement char instead of erroring, you can use [`String::from_utf8_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy)